# Do Xamarin support in-app purchases

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin

I would think it supports this, but I cant find any documentation about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, look at the [StoreKit](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=N%3aMonoTouch.StoreKit) API.